# Calculating the Galois cohomology of $U(n)$

Tags: algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

I would like to know know what the Galois cohomology $H^1(Gal( \Bbb{C}/\Bbb{R}),U(n)(\Bbb{C}) )   $  is.

The unitary group $U(n)$ can be defined as the real form of $Gl_{n,\Bbb{C}}$ relative to the involution $\phi$ sending $A\mapsto (\bar{A}^\top)^{-1}$. Then explicitily
$$H^1(Gal( \Bbb{C}/\Bbb{R}),U(n)(\Bbb{C}) )=\{g\in GL( \Bbb{C}^n)\mid g \phi(g)=I\} /\sim $$
where the equivalence relation is induced by $ g\sim Ag\phi(A)^{-1}$ for $A\in GL(\Bbb{C}^n)$. See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/First_cohomology_set_with_coefficients_in_a_non-abelian_group) for the exact definition of the first non-abelian cohomology group.

The case $n=1$ is easy and shows that the Galois cohomology is trivial, but I assume it is non-trivial for higher $n$.

Comment: I use the definition in https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/First_cohomology_set_with_coefficients_in_a_non-abelian_group, but I will edit the question to make the equivalence relation clearer

Comment: I xan write a full answer later, but you should start by rethinking your computation for $n=1$. Namely, for $n=1$ you should get $\mathbb{R}^\times/\mathrm{Nm}(\mathbb{C}^\times)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I already had the correct LHS, but in a hustle I thought the norm map was surjective...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$$\newcommand{\Res}{\mathrm{Res}}$$\newcommand{\ad}{\mathrm{ad}}$$\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}$$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$$\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\newcommand{\ov}[1]{\overline{#1}}$$\newcommand{\GL}{\mathrm{GL}}$

### Notation and terminology

To make our lives easier, let us fix the following notation/terminology:

- if $G$ is an algebraic group over a field $F$ then we shall write $H^i(F,G)$ as shorthand for $H^i(\Gal(\ov{F}/F),G(\ov{F})$,
- for such a $G$, let us also write $G^\ast$ for the unique quasi-split inner form of $G$ (e.g., see [Mil, Corollary 23.54]),
- a form that is not inner is called outer.

### Forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$

Let us begin by clarifying that $U(n)$ is ambiguous. Over $\R$ there are many groups which are called 'unitary groups'. I think the following is probably the least contentious definition.

> **Definition 1:** A *unitary group* over $\mathbb{R}$ is an outer form of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$.

Now, the forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ are easy to understand. There is a decomposition

$$\mathrm{Form}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}})=\bigsqcup_{x\in X}\mathrm{InnForm}(G_x),$$

where $X$ is a set of representatives from the inner-form classes of the forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$, and $G_x$ is a(ny) representative of $X$. But, we can easily compute $\#(X)$. Indeed, as in [Mil, Theorem 23.52] there is a bijection

$$X\xrightarrow{\sim} H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}),\mathrm{Out}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{C}})),$$

where $\mathrm{Out}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{C}})=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{C}})/\mathrm{Inn}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}})$ has the obvious Galois action. (I'm being a little imprecise here about outer forms vs. outer twists, but let's not worry about that)

But, the outermorphism group of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ is easy to compute using root data (e.g., see [Mil, Corollary 23.46]) and in this case it's easy to compute that it's $\mathbb{Z}/2$ with the trivial Galois action (the non-trivial outermorphism corresponding to $g\mapsto (g^t)^{-1}$). So, it's then easy to see that

$$\#(X)=\# H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}),\mathrm{Out}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{C}}))=\# \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z}/2)=2.$$

As we may certainly take $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ as one element of $X$, it suffices to find any other outer form $G$ of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ to fill out $X$.

To this end, for $p,q\in\N$ such that $p+q=n$ let us consider

$$U(p,q)=\left\{g\in \Res_{\C/\R}\,\GL_{n,\C}: g^\ast J_{p,q} g=J_{p,q}\right\},$$

where $g^\ast=\ov{g}^t$, and $J_{p,q}=\mathrm{antidiag}(I_p,-I_q)$, where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix.

The following lemma is elementary and left to the reader.

> **Lemma 2:** For any $p,q\in\N$ with $p+q=n$ the group $U(p,q)\simeq U(q,p)$. Moreover, if $p\geqslant q$, then $U(p,q)$ is a form of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$, has maximally split maximal torus isomorphic to
> $(\Res_{\C/\R}\,\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}})^{q}\times U(1)^{p-q}$, and center isomorphic to
> $U(1)$.

Here

$$U(1)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}\in \Res_{\C/\R}\,\GL_{n,\R}: a^2+b^2=1\right\},$$

is the circle group, a (the) non-split one-dimensional torus over $\mathbb{R}$.

From this, it's easy to deduce that among pairs $p,q\in\N$ with $p+q=n$ and $p\geqslant q$ that

- $U(p,q)$ is an outer form of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\R}$ (as inner forms have isomorphic centers),
- no two are isomorphic to each other (by counting the split rank of a maximally split maximal torus).

Thus, any $U(p,q)$ may constitute the other element of $X$ and, in fact, we thus deduce that any two $U(p,q)$ are an inner forms of each other.

Let us write $U(n):=U(n,0)\simeq U(0,n)$. Then, we conclude that

$$\mathrm{Form}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}})=\mathrm{InnForm}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}})\sqcup \mathrm{InnForm}(U(n))\qquad (1).$$

### Galois cohomology of $U(n)$

Let us begin by calculating the Galois cohomology groups $H^1(\mathbb{R},U(n))$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R},U(n)^\mathrm{ad})$.

Our key result is the following:

> **Theorem 3([Bor, Theorem 3.1]):** Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $T$ be a fundamental torus of $G$ (i.e., one of minimal split rank). Then, there is a canonical bijection
> $$H^1(\mathbb{R},T)/W_T(\mathbb{R})\to H^1(\mathbb{R},G).$$

Here $W_T$ be the *Weyl group scheme*,
$$W_T:=N_G(T)/T.$$
Observe that $W_T(\mathbb{R})$ naturally acts on $H^1(\mathbb{R},T)$ in way equivariant for for the projection to $H^1(\mathbb{R},G)$, so this induces the natural map in the theorem.

Let us apply this to the case when $U(n)$. In particular, note that by Lemma 2, $T=U(1)^n$ is a fundamental torus of $U(n)$. So, we first need to calculate $H^1(\mathbb{R},U(1))$.

> **Lemma 4:** The following equalities holds for $i>0$:
>
> $$H^i(\R,U(1))=\begin{cases}\R^\times/\mathrm{Nm}(\C^\times) &
>  \mbox{if}\quad i\text{ is odd}\\ 0 & \mbox{if}\quad i\text{ is even}.\end{cases}$$
> $$H^i(\R,\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}})=\begin{cases}\R^\times/\mathrm{Nm}(\C^\times) &
>  \mbox{if}\quad i\text{ is even}\\ 0 & \mbox{if}\quad i\text{ is odd}.\end{cases},$$ where $\mathrm{Nm}\colon \C^\times\to\R^\times$ is the norm map.

*Proof:* We have a short exact sequence

$$1\to U(1)\to \Res_{\C/\R}\,\bb{G}_{m,\C}\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Nm}} \bb{G}_{m,\R}\to 1,$$

where $\mathrm{Nm}$ is the norm map. We then get a long exact sequence

$$1\to U(1)(\R)\to \C^\times\to\R^\times\to H^1(\R,U(1))\to H^1(\R,\Res_{\C/\R}\,\bb{G}_{m,\C})\to H^1(\R,\bb{G}_{m,\R})\to\cdots.$$

By Shapiro's lemma we know that

$$H^i(\R,\Res_{\C/\R}\bb{G}_{m,\C})=0,\qquad i>0$$

And, thus we deduce that $$H^{i+1}(\R,U(1))\simeq H^{i}(\R,\mathbb{G}_{m,\R})$$ for $i>1$. Moreover, we see that $$H^1(\R,U(1))=\C^\times/\mathrm{Nm}(\R^\times).$$ We thus reduce the calculation for $U(1)$ to that of $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}$ which is easy because one is just computing $H^i(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{C}^\times)$ where the non-trivial element of $\Z/2$ acts by conjugation. $\blacksquare$

Of course, $\mathrm{Nm}(\C^\times)=\R^{>0}$ and thus $\R^\times/\mathrm{Nm}(\C^\times)\cong\Z/2$.

$$H^1(\mathbb{R},T)=H^1(\mathbb{R},U(1)^n)=H^1(\mathbb{R},U(1))^n=(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$$

To proceed further we ned the following fun exercise (a proof can be found at loc. cit.).

> **Lemma 5:** Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $T$ is a fundamental torus. Then, the group scheme $W_T$ is constant.

In particular, returning to the case of $U(n)$ and $T=U(1)^n$, we see that
$$W_T(\mathbb{R})=W_T(\mathbb{C})=S_n,$$
where we are using the fact that $U(n)_{\mathbb{C}}\simeq \mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{C}}$ whose Weyl group is $S_n$, acting by permuting the factors. In particular, It's not hard to see that $S_n$ acts on

$$H^1(\mathbb{R},U(1)^n)\simeq H^1(\mathbb{R},U(1))^n\simeq (\C^\times/\mathrm{Nm}(\R^\times))^n\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2)^n,$$
by permuting factors the factors.

Thus, making the identification

$$(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n/S_n\simeq\{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n\},$$

we deduce the following calculation.

> **Proposition 6:** There is a natural bijection $$H^1(\mathbb{R},U(n))\simeq \{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n\}.$$

To compute $H^1(\mathbb{R},U(n)^\mathrm{ad})$ we could repeat a similar argument. But, perhaps it's fun to instead use the exact sequence

$$H^1(\R,U(1))\to H^1(\R,U(n))\to H^1(\R,U(n)^{\ad})\to H^2(\R,U(1)).$$

By Lemma 4 this last group vanishes and the first group is isomorphic to $\Z/2$, and so we arrive at the exact sequence. Thus, we arrive at the sequence

$$\Z/2\Z\to H^1(\R,U(n))\to H^1(\R,U(n)^{\ad})\to 0.$$

By [Ser,§5.7], we deduce that there is a natural $\Z/2\Z$ action on $H^1(\R,U(n))$ whose orbit space can be identified with $H^1(\R,U(n)^{\ad}$. One can verify that the non-trivial element of $\Z/2$ acts on

$$H^1(\mathbb{R},U(n))\simeq \{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n\},$$

is via the transposition $(p,q)\mapsto (q,p)$.

Thus, all in all, we deduce the following

> **Proposition 7:** The map $$H^1(\mathbb{R},U(n))\to H^1(\R,U(n)^\mathrm{ad})$$ is surjective and may be identified with
> the obvious map $$\{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n\}\to
>  \{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n\text{ and }p\geqslant q\}.$$

### Forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$

We can now actually completely describe all of the forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ and their Galois cohomology. By Equation (1) it suffices to compute the inner forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ and $U(n)$. We then use the following fact.

> **Lemma 8 (cf., [Mil, Corollary 23.48]):** Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{R}$. There is a bijection
> $$\mathrm{InnForm}(G)\simeq H^1(\R,G^\ad).$$

Now, in Proposition 7 we already calculated that $H^1(\R,U(n)^\ad)$ is in bijection with $\{(p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^2:p+q=n\text{ and }p\geqslant q\}$. By Lemma 2, we know that the groups $U(p,q)$, as $(p,q)$ ranges over such pairs, form non-isomorphic inner forms of $U(n)$. We thus deduce the following.

> **Corollary 9:** The following equality holds $$\mathrm{InnForm}(U(n))=\left\{U(p,q):(p,q)\in \N^2\text{ and
>  }p+q=n\text{ with }p\geqslant q.\right\}.$$

To compute the cohomology of $U(p,q)$ we recall the following definition.

> **Definition 10:** Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\R$. An inner form of $G$ is called *pure* if its associated class in
> $H^1(\R,G^\ad)$ (as in Lemma 8) is in $\mathrm{im}\left(H^1(\R,G)\to
>  H^1(\R,G^\ad)\right)$.

We then have the following basic calculation.

> **Proposition 11 ([Kne, §1.4, Lemma]):** Let $H$ be a pure inner form of $G$. Then, there is a natural bijection
> $H^1(\R,G)\xrightarrow{\sim}H^1(\R,H)$.

Now, by Proposition 7 we have that $H^1(\R,U(n))\to H^1(\R,U(n)^\ad)$ is surjective, and so every inner form of $U(n)$ is pure. So, we deduce that for any unitary group $U$ we have that

$$H^1(\R,U)\simeq \{(p,q)\in \N^2:p+q=n\text{ and }p\geqslant q\},$$

and so, in particular, for each $U=U(p,q)$.

To calculate the inner forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\R}$, we use the exact sequence

$$1\to \mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{R}}\to\GL_{n,\R}\to\mathrm{PGL}_{n,\R}\to 1,$$

which, with Hilbert'9 Theorem 90 and Lemma 4, gives us an exact sequence of pointed sets

$$1\to H^1(\R,\mathrm{PGL}_{n,\R})\to \Z/2.$$

It's not hard to show that this map is actually *bijective* if $n$ is even, and trivial if $n$ is odd (e.g., see [Sza, §4.4]). So, we get that $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\R}$ has no non-trivial inner forms if $n$ is odd, and one if $n$ is even. I leave it for you to check that if $n=2m$, and $A_m:=\mathrm{Mat}_{m\times m}(\mathbb{H})$ (where $\mathbb{H}$ are Hamilton's quaternions) then the units $A_m^\times$ are an inner form of $\GL_{n,\R}$. The Galois cohomology $H^1(\R,A_m^\times)$ is trivial as follows from Generalized Hilbert's Theorem 90 (see [Kne, §1.7, Example 1]).

Thus, all in all, we deduce the following omnibus result.

> **Proposition 12:** There is a decomposition $$\mathrm{Form}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\R})=\mathrm{InnForm}(\mathrm{GL}_{n,\R})\sqcup
> \mathrm{InnForm}(U(n)).$$ There are further equalities
> $$\mathrm{InnForm}(\GL_{n,\R})=\begin{cases} \{\GL_{n,\R}\} &
>  \mbox{if}\quad n\text{ is odd}\\ \{\GL_{n,\R},A_m^\times\} & \mbox{if}\quad
>  n=2m.\end{cases}$$ and $$\mathrm{InnForm}(U(n))=\{U(s,t):
>  (s,t)\in\N^2\text{ and }s+t=n\text{ with }s\geqslant t\}.$$
> Furtheremore, we have that
> $$H^1(\R,\GL_{n,\R})=H^1(\R,A_m^\times),$$ are trivial and
> $$H^1(\R,U(s,t))\simeq \{(p,q)\in \N^2: p+q=n\}.$$

### References

[Bor] Borovoi, M., 2023. Galois cohomology of reductive algebraic groups over the field of real numbers. Communications in Mathematics, 30.

[Kne] Kneser, M. and Jothilingam, P., 1969. Lectures on Galois cohomology of classical groups (No. 47). Bombay: Tata Institute of Fundamental Research.

[Mil] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.

[Sza] Gille, P. and Szamuely, T., 2017. Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology (Vol. 165). Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks for the beautiful answer. It is exactly in the spirit of what I expected. There are some points left: How do I know that the forms of $Gl_{n,\Bbb{R}}$ are exactly given by the inner forms of the groups mentioned above? I assume your $U(n)^*$ is just $U(n/2,n/2)$ in the even case (and similar for the odd one)? How do I classify the inner forms of $U(n)^*$? I am aware that these questions possibly deserve their own thread, but you are welcome to elaborate or hint to references!

Comment: @Notone The forms of a group are classified by the inner forms of the quasi-split forms of that group. The quasi-split forms are classified by $H^1(k,\mathrm{Out}(G))$. For $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$ you have that $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial action. So, the outer classes are given by elements of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k),\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ which are degree $2$ etale algebras over $k$ (i.e. $k^2$ or a degree $2$ extension). For $k=\mathbb{R}$ there are then two outer classes, so two quasi-split forms of $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: They are $\mathrm{GL}_{n,\mathbb{R}}$ and some other quasi-split form. As $U(n)^\ast$ is also quasi-split it must be the other outer form.  The first claim then follows. In this case $U(n)^\ast$ is either $U(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2})$ or $U(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2})$ depending on parity. Classifyiing the inner forms is somewhat classical. It just comes from thinking about descent data. You can find details in something like Platonov and Rapinchuk section 2.3.1

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: Note that at least in spirit (i.e. modulo reducing the reductive to the semisimple case and the group to the Lie algebra), classification of the real forms can also be reduced to classification of the real forms of the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$, e.g. with Satake-Tits diagrams; see e.g. the inner forms in row 1&2, and the outer forms in row 3&4 [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&pg=PA229&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Notone I edited the answer with an approach that applies more generally.

Comment: Thanks for providing the two alternatives. In fact I have considered Borovoi's paper, but wasn't able to fill in all the details. I assume for the Lemma you show that $W_T(\Bbb{C})\subset Aut(X(T))$ is stable under the Galois action.

Comment: @Notone Or rather you show that the Galois action is trivial. I wrote a proof of this once in the course of a paper I was writing. I can try and dig it up if you'd like, but maybe it's worth working on for yourself first.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I seem to be stuck. Every real cocharacter factors through the center $Z(G)$, but I am not sure how to go on from here.

Comment: @Notone If you want you can email me and (assuming my collaborator doesn't mind) I can share the proof with you. My email is (first name).(last name) at gmail.