# Is galois cohomology invariant under inner forms and not just pure inner forms?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G, G'$ be smooth algebraic groups over $k$ (absolute Galois group $\Gamma$) which are etale **inner** forms of each other, that is, there exists an isomorphism $G_{k_s} \cong G'_{k_s}$ and the associated torsor for the automorphism group is in the image of the natural map $H^1(k, G/Z_G) \to H^1(k, \operatorname{Aut}_G)$. My question is about the truth of the following proposition:

**Proposition:** Each inner isomorphism $G_{k_s} \cong G'_{k_s}$ induces a bijection $H^1(k, G) \xrightarrow{\sim} H^1(k, G')$.

Is this true as stated, or only for **pure** inner forms? Does it follow if we make any further assumptions on $G$ (affine, reductive, semisimple . . .)?

This is asserted a few places, e.g. the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333070/calculating-the-galois-cohomology-of-un). However, the linked proof [here](https://mathweb.tifr.res.in/sites/default/files/publications/ln/tifr47.pdf) (as in Serre's *Cohomologie Galoisienne*), only works for **pure** inner forms, i.e. those corresponding to cocycles that factor through $H^1(k, G) \to H^1(k, G/Z_G) \to H^1(k, \operatorname{Aut}_G)$.

#### Proof for pure inner forms

The argument, as I understand it, goes as follows.

*Proof for pure inner forms:* Let $s \in \Gamma \mapsto g_s \in G(k_s)$ be a Galois cocycle in $H^1(k, G)$, with associated cocycle valued in $\operatorname{Aut}_G$ given by conjugation, $s \mapsto \left(h \mapsto g_s h g_s^{-1}\right)$. Let $G'$ be the pure inner form of $G$ defined by this latter cocycle. In particular, $G'(k_s) = G(k_s)$, and the two galois actions are related by $s \cdot'(g) = g_s(s \cdot g) g_s^{-1}$.

We define a map $H^1(k, G) \to H^1(k, G')$ on cocycles now as follows: given $s \mapsto a_s \in G(k_s) = G'(k_s)$ a cocycle for the $G$-Galois action, we can define a cocycle for the $G'$-Galois action by $s \mapsto b_s := a_s g_s^{-1}$. This is indeed a cocycle:
$$
b_{s} s \cdot'(b_t) = a_s g_s^{-1} g_s(s \cdot(a_t g_t^{-1})) g_s^{-1} = a_s s \cdot(a_t) \; g_{st}^{-1} = a_{st} g_{st}^{-1},
$$
easily seen to descend to $H^1(k, G)$, and has inverse given by right multiplication by $g_s$ instead. QED.

#### My Thoughts

In the proof above, if $s \mapsto g_s \in (G/Z_G)(k_s) = G(k_s)/Z_G(k_s)$ is valued in the inner automorphism group, then the expression $s \mapsto b_s = a_s g_s^{-1}$ is only well-defined up to an element of the center, and the failure of the identity $g_s s(g_t) = g_{st}$ at the level of $G$ (which was used in checking $b_s$ was a cocycle) is measured by a 2-cocycle valued in $Z_G$. If this 2-cocycle is not a coboundary, we should not expect to be able to choose a cocycle lifting the $g_s$ to $G(k_s)$.

In other words, we should run into the difficulty that the map $H^1(k, G) \to H^1(k, G/Z_G)$ is rarely surjective, fitting into the LES
$$
H^1(k, Z_G) \longrightarrow H^1(k, G) \longrightarrow H^1(k, G/Z_G) \longrightarrow H^2(k, Z_G).
$$
For $\operatorname{GL}_n$, for example, $Z_G = \mathbb{G}_m$, and so the Brauer group provides an obstruction to lifting cocycles from $\operatorname{PGL}_n$ to $\operatorname{GL}_n$. I haven't been able to construct a counterexample among the forms of $\operatorname{GL}_n$, however.

Comment: You are citing my answer as justification. I just want to comment that I don't think I intended to claim it for arbitrary inner forms, opposed to pure inner forms -- I can't remember if I stated it that way out of ignorance or uncarefulness. I only know this result to be true for pure inner forms. This is not an issue with this post as $H^1(\mathbb{R},U(N)^\ast)\to H^1(\mathbb{R},U(N)^{\ast,\mathrm{ad}})$$ is surjective (as I explain later in that post), so all inner forms are pure there. I don't know a counterexample off-hand, but I will mention that I think the result you want is true

Comment: over.a $p$-adic field as follows from Kottwitz's isomorphism of $H^1(F,G)$ with $\pi_0(Z(\widehat{G})^\Gamma)^\vee$, so it will need to be something a bit more exotic. I guess it also can't work for $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$ as this group has no pure inner forms, but all of its inner forms have the same (vanishing) Galois cohomology by Generalized Hilbert's Theorem 90. I'll try to think of a counterexample tomorrow. I will certainly at least fix my other answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: PS, by Generalized Hilbert's Theorem 90 I mean Example 1 of §1.7 of https://mathweb.tifr.res.in/sites/default/files/publications/ln/tifr47.pdf

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the response -- wasn't sure if you'd notice a comment to the old question, so thought I'd just ask myself. Your  reasoning is the same I had for suspecting the result might still be true: seems like several miraculous things happened in the two inner classes of the $\operatorname{GL}_{n, \mathbb{R}}$ case in order to ensure the result is still true.

Comment: Hey, so I've edited the other post to fix the issue. I am still not sure on an answer to this. I will think more later if I have time.